# Laravel 5 can't find class for custom namespace

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5, autoload

In my Laravel app I'm splitting the front end and back end code into folder. These are `app/Http/Controllers/BackEnd` and `app/Http/Controllers/FrontEnd`. Rather than type all that out on every file I thought it would be easier to define two namespaces, `BackEnd` and `FrontEnd`. I've edited my composer file to this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/Models",
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "BackEnd\\": "app/Http/Controllers/BackEnd",
        "FrontEnd\\": "app/Http/Controllers/FrontEnd"
    }
},
```

I then ran composer autodump and set up my route file like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'webman', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'BackEnd'], function()
{
   Route::get('/', ['as' => 'webmanHome', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']); 
});
```

But when I browse to `localhost:8000/webman/` I just get an error, `Class App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd\HomeController does not exist`. The controller does exist, this is the file:

```
<?php namespace BackEnd;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display the admin home page, showing the front-end menu and "apps" as links to other sections of the ACP.
     *
     * @param Reqeust       $request
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('backend.index');
    }

}
```

I've checked `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` to make sure that the namespace is being defined and it is, this is in the array returned `'BackEnd\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/BackEnd'),`.

Strangely if I use `<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd;` at the top of `HomeController.php` then everything works, why? What am I missing? Why can't autoload find the file with just `BackEnd`?

Comment: maybe your blade template tries to access controller at wrong location. (if you are using 'action' refer) so specify controller in blade like BackEnd\HomeController@lala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When setting `namespace` in `Route::group()` it is actually appending that to `App\Http\Controllers`. What you could do is remove it and reference the full path like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'webman', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'webmanHome', 'uses' => '\BackEnd\HomeController@index']); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue. Can you please explain why using `'namespace' => '\BackEnd'` doesn't work either?

Comment: The `namespace` value is getting trimmed of slashes and then appended to `App\Http\Controllers`. Take a look in the source, and specifically the `formatUsesPrefix()` method in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing/commenting the below line in RouteServiceProvider.php

`protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to include info about what this does and how this is likely to break other routes.

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting and easy way to get around this... Service Providers.

When the route file is loaded via a provider, the 'App\Http...' is not enforced.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(app_path('Your/Model/routes.php'));
}
```

Keep in mind no middleware is attached either. Your route group will have to specify a 'web' middleware or you'll go nuts wondering why validation, etc, isn't working anymore....(been there!)

It's a cool way to go about it anyway, using providers leads to more modular code and re-use.